# How to upgrade version of pyenv on Ubuntu

Tags: python, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I wanted to install python 3.10 but that version is not available on pyenv version list.
checked by `pyenv install --list`.
People suggested to upgrade pyenv that but I do not see help related to updating pyenv.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`pyenv` isn't really 'installed' in a traditional sense, it's just a git checkout. All you have to do to update is

```
cd ~/.pyenv
git pull
```

That also updates the list of available python versions.

Comment: One has to be on their `master` branch for this to work

Answer (score 4):

Received the `not a git repository` error and found out I have installed pyenv through Homebrew. This means you have to run:
`brew upgrade pyenv`

Another option is you have installed it with pyenv installer, then you should run `pyenv update`. See full [pyenv docs](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#upgrading).